# Date format to cron dormat conversion

Tags: python-3.x, shell, scripting, command

I want to change the date format into cron date format.How could it be done?

date format : 2018-05-15 17:30:00
cron format : 30 17 15 05 *

Comment: What have you tried? Add some code examples

Comment: Thanks. i used slicing.

Comment: You can edit your post and add some code examples. Also take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You could do that in a number of ways, but this is one of the more straightforward methods:

```
#!/bin/bash
_DATESTR='2018-05-15 17:30:00'
echo "date format: ${_DATESTR}"
echo "cron format: ${_DATESTR:14:2} ${_DATESTR:11:2} ${_DATESTR:8:2} ${_DATESTR:5:2} *"
```